# Problema com responsividade com html/css

Tags: html, css

Estou treinando meu html/css tentando recriar a página home do youtube, mas, quando o site chega a uma certa largura, o background-color do header fica zoado, como mostra a imagem. Alguém pode me dizer o que seria e o que posso fazer pra tentar resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Youtube</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="search">
            <div id="menu">
                <div class="menu_line"></div>
                <div class="menu_line"></div>
                <div class="menu_line"></div>
            </div>
            <img src="assets/imgs/yt_logo.png" class="yt_logo">
            <div class="search_bar">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="Pesquisar" placeholder="Pesquisar" autocomplete="off">
                </form>
                <button id="search_button">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/search.png" id="search_icon">
                    </a>
                </button>
                <div class="speaker">
                    <img src="assets/imgs/microfone.png" class="speakericon">
                </div>
            </div>     
            <div class="mobile_search">
                <img src="assets/imgs/search.png" id="msearch_icon">
            </div>       
        <div class="right_nav">
            <div class="right_nav_icons">
                <img src="assets/imgs/upload.png" class="icons">
            </div>
            <div class="right_nav_icons">
                <img src="assets/imgs/apps.png" class="icons">
            </div>
            <div class="right_nav_icons">
                <img src="assets/imgs/bell.png" class="icons">
            </div>
            <div class="profilepic">
                <img src="assets/imgs/profpic.jpg" id="profpic">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
header {
    background-color: #202020;
    height: 56px;
    display: flex;
}
.search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.menu_line {
    display: flex;
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #767676;
}
.yt_logo {
    width: 96px;
    height: 24px;
    display: flex;
}
.search_bar {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.search_bar input {
    width: 550px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #121212;
    border: solid 2px #2d2d2d;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    outline: none;
}
#search_button {
    justify-content: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 39px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border: solid 2px #2d2d2d;
    border-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
.speaker {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    background-color: #181818;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.speakericon {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
#search_icon {
    margin: auto;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
}
.right_nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 20%;
}
.right_nav_icons {
    display: flex;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.profilepic {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 2px #bfbfbf;
}
.icons {
    margin: auto;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
#profpic {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.mobile_search {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
}
#msearch_icon {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

@media (max-width:1024px) {
    .search {
        width: 98%;
    }
    .search_bar input {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .search {
        width: 95%;
    }
    .search_bar input {
        width: 250px;
    }
    .right_nav {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .right_nav_icons {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    .icons {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    .profilepic {
        margin-right: 0px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    #profpic {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }

}
@media (max-width:425px) {
    .search_bar {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile_search {
        display: flex;
    }
    
}
@media (max-width:375px) {
    .search_bar {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile_search {
        display: flex;
    }
    #msearch_icon {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    
}
@media (max-width:320px) {
    .search_bar {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile_search {
        display: flex;
    }
    #msearch_icon {
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    .right_nav_icons {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    .icons {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    .profilepic {
        margin-right: 0px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
    #profpic {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
    #menu {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .menu_line {
        width: 20px;
        height: 2px;
    }
    .yt_logo {
        width: 64px;
        height: 16px;
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está atribuindo muitas classes para seus código. Sugiro que tente limpar mais seu código para tentarmos realiza um checklist na atribuição do problema. Um grande exemplo que percebi que seu código possui as propriedades de flex, porem para entender onde se encontra o problema seu codigo precisa está mais limpo.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e fornecer um [mcve] do problema no lugar do código original, junto de uma explicação detalhada do que saiu diferente do esperado. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

O conteudo em preto esta no tamanho correto em que a tela deveria estar, mas por ter muitos icones em um certo tamanho de tela eles quebram e ultrapassam o tamanho que a tela deveria realmente ser, ou seja, tudo que esta fora da area em preto esta ultrapassando o limite visivel da tela.

Você pode testar isso atravéz desse código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Youtube</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        header {
            background-color: #202020;
            height: 56px;
            display: flex;
        }
        .search {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #menu {
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: flex;
            margin: 20px;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .menu_line {
            display: flex;
            width: 25px;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: #767676;
        }
        .yt_logo {
            width: 96px;
            height: 24px;
            display: flex;
        }
        .search_bar {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .search_bar input {
            width: 550px;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: #121212;
            border: solid 2px #2d2d2d;
            color: #ddd;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 1px;
            outline: none;
        }
        #search_button {
            justify-content: center;
            width: 60px;
            height: 39px;
            background-color: #1f1f1f;
            border: solid 2px #2d2d2d;
            border-left: 0;
            margin-left: 0;
            border-radius: 1px;
        }
        .speaker {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 39px;
            height: 39px;
            background-color: #181818;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        .speakericon {
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        #search_icon {
            margin: auto;
            width: 19px;
            height: 19px;
        }
        .right_nav {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            max-width: 20%;
        }
        .right_nav_icons {
            display: flex;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        .profilepic {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            align-items: center;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            border: solid 2px #bfbfbf;
        }
        .icons {
            margin: auto;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }
        #profpic {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        .mobile_search {
            display: none;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        #msearch_icon {
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            margin: 10px;
            margin-left: 80px;
        }

        @media (max-width:1024px) {
            .search {
                width: 98%;
            }
            .search_bar input {
                max-width: 300px;
            }
        }
        @media (max-width:768px) {
            .search {
                width: 95%;
            }
            .search_bar input {
                width: 250px;
            }
            .right_nav {
                width: 150px;
                display: none;
            }
            .right_nav_icons {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
            }
            .icons {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
            }
            .profilepic {
                margin-right: 0px;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
            }
            #profpic {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
            }

        }
        @media (max-width:425px) {
            .search_bar {
                display: none;
            }
            .mobile_search {
                display: flex;
            }
            
        }
        @media (max-width:375px) {
            .search_bar {
                display: none;
            }
            .mobile_search {
                display: flex;
            }
            #msearch_icon {
                margin-left: 30px;
            }
            
        }
        @media (max-width:320px) {
            .search_bar {
                display: none;
            }
            .mobile_search {
                display: flex;
            }
            #msearch_icon {
                margin-left: 40px;
            }
            .right_nav_icons {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
            }
            .icons {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
            }
            .profilepic {
                margin-right: 0px;
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
            }
            #profpic {
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
            }
            #menu {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                margin: 10px;
            }
            .menu_line {
                width: 20px;
                height: 2px;
            }
            .yt_logo {
                width: 64px;
                height: 16px;
                display: flex;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="search">
            <div id="menu">
                <div class="menu_line"></div>
                <div class="menu_line"></div>
                <div class="menu_line"></div>
            </div>
            <img src="assets/imgs/yt_logo.png" class="yt_logo">
            <div class="search_bar">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="Pesquisar" placeholder="Pesquisar" autocomplete="off">
                </form>
                <button id="search_button">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/search.png" id="search_icon">
                    </a>
                </button>
                <div class="speaker">
                    <img src="assets/imgs/microfone.png" class="speakericon">
                </div>
            </div>     
            <div class="mobile_search">
                <img src="assets/imgs/search.png" id="msearch_icon">
            </div>       
        <div class="right_nav">
            <div class="right_nav_icons">
                <img src="assets/imgs/upload.png" class="icons">
            </div>
            <div class="right_nav_icons">
                <img src="assets/imgs/apps.png" class="icons">
            </div>
            <div class="right_nav_icons">
                <img src="assets/imgs/bell.png" class="icons">
            </div>
            <div class="profilepic">
                <img src="assets/imgs/profpic.jpg" id="profpic">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Na linha 154, adicionei um `display: none` para ocultar o conteudo que expandiu alem do tamanho que deveria ocupar.